# Javascript not equal and OR

Tags: javascript

This looks a simple code but not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
var data = "[{\"Id\":\"01\",\"Name\":\"01- Alabama\"},{\"Id\":\"02\",\"Name\":\"02- Arizona\"},{\"Id\":\"03\",\"Name\":\"03- Arkansas\"}]";

 var myJson = JSON.parse(data);
 for (var key in myJson) {
   var item = {
   Id: myJson[key].Id,
   Name: myJson[key].Name
 };

 if(item.Id != "01" || item.Id !="02")
 {
   alert(item.Id);   
 }
}
```

I am expecting to just show an alert as "03" but it shows 3 alert each for "01", "02" & "03"

Looks like != and OR operator not working ?

Comment: You want an AND not an OR.

Comment: Think about it logically and step through your code. when `item.Id` is "01", the first half of the OR is false, but the second half of the OR is true, so it evaluates to true. When `item.Id` is "02", the halves switch, but the outcome is still true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `||` operator only returns `false` when both of its operands are `false` (and `true` in all other cases).

The `&&` operator only returns `true` when both of its operands are `true` (and `false` in all other cases).

You have to use `&&` instead of `||` in the if condition to get the expected result:

```js
var data = "[{\"Id\":\"01\",\"Name\":\"01- Alabama\"},{\"Id\":\"02\",\"Name\":\"02- Arizona\"},{\"Id\":\"03\",\"Name\":\"03- Arkansas\"}]";

 var myJson = JSON.parse(data);
 for (var key in myJson) {
   var item = {
   Id: myJson[key].Id,
   Name: myJson[key].Name
 };

 if(item.Id != "01" && item.Id !="02")
 {
   alert(item.Id);   
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually is working as expected because the `OR` operator is returning `true` for cases when `Id == 01` and `Id == 02`

What you want to do is to join the two operands with AND operator `&&` and this way execute the logic just when `Id != 01` **AND** `Id != 02`.

```js
var data = "[{\"Id\":\"01\",\"Name\":\"01- Alabama\"},{\"Id\":\"02\",\"Name\":\"02- Arizona\"},{\"Id\":\"03\",\"Name\":\"03- Arkansas\"}]";

var myJson = JSON.parse(data);
for (var key in myJson) {
  var item = {
    Id: myJson[key].Id,
    Name: myJson[key].Name
  };

  if (item.Id != "01" && item.Id != "02") {
    alert(item.Id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`item.Id != "01" || item.Id !="02"` will always be true, as it can't be equal to both of the values at the same time.

You only need to use `&&` instead of `||`:

```js
var data = "[{\"Id\":\"01\",\"Name\":\"01- Alabama\"},{\"Id\":\"02\",\"Name\":\"02- Arizona\"},{\"Id\":\"03\",\"Name\":\"03- Arkansas\"}]";

 var myJson = JSON.parse(data);
 for (var key in myJson) {
   var item = {
   Id: myJson[key].Id,
   Name: myJson[key].Name
 };

 if(item.Id != "01" && item.Id !="02")
 {
   console.log(item.Id); // I prefer consoling, that's less agressive!
 }
}
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

If you also plan to do `if(item.Id != "01" && item.Id !="02" && item.Id !="03")`, you must want to use a `>` comparator and unary `+` on your string:

```js
var data = "[{\"Id\":\"01\",\"Name\":\"01- Alabama\"},{\"Id\":\"02\",\"Name\":\"02- Arizona\"},{\"Id\":\"03\",\"Name\":\"03- Arkansas\"}]";

 var myJson = JSON.parse(data);
 for (var key in myJson) {
   var item = {
   Id: myJson[key].Id,
   Name: myJson[key].Name
 };

 if(+item.Id > 2)
 {
   console.log(item.Id); // I prefer consoling, that's less agressive!
 }
}
```

Hope it helps.